# Why was I notified for another user's mentions?

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

I logged into Stack Overflow and saw that I had three notifications; turns out those notifications were meant for another user:

[image]

I've gone in and checked the chat message where I was apparently mentioned; none of them were edited:

> [@tchrist just using @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ with an @ before it.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4003436#4003436)

and this:

> [@ᔕᖺᘎᕊ test](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4003384#4003384)

and also this:

> [@ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Check your GH](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4003346#4003346)

Why was I 'pinged' when another user was mentioned?
Was this supposed to happen, or is this a bug of some kind?

Comment: look at the star wall

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks! I did check first but the title of that question isn't the best.

Comment: @cybermonkey: sorry, at the time when this was happening the title did reflect what was going on.  (Edited in the mean time)

Comment: Wow. The USE contacted you to check your GH.